# Game Kit loadMatchDataWithCompletionHandler never loads match data

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

I'm building a turn based game kit application and I'm saving and retrieving data using:

```
saveCurrentTurnWithMatchData:jsonData completionHandler:^(NSError *error)
loadMatchDataWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *matchData, NSError *error)
```

I Get all the matches using this:

```
 [GKTurnBasedMatch loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *matches, NSError *error) {
```

and save each of the matches to an array and call the laodMatchData method when I need it. The problem is that the completion handler never returns anything. I guess it's stuck gettings the data and never gets back to me. It loads sometimes but more often than not, it just keeps loading.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with iOS7 beta 1. The problem is solved now.